# How does $|iw|=3|1-w|$ go to $|w|=3|w-1|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well the question speaks for itself really.

I worked the problem down to

$|iw|=3|1-w|$, where i is the imaginary number,

but I don't understand how to get to the next step, which the mark scheme tells me is

$|w|=3|w-1|$.

Why can you just flip it round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|ab|=|a||b|$$ where $a,b$ are complex

Here $a=i,b=w$

Again,
$$a=-1\implies|-b|=|b|\implies |w-1|=|1-w|$$